# How to wait until a userform is created

Tags: excel, vba

At first, apologize for my english.

I have programmatically created a userform, but when I try to change properties (when "With m_FormProgressBar"),  an error occurs (Error 75). It seems the object hasn't been created yet.

Any idea?

```
'Creo el UserForm
    Set m_FormProgressBar = ThisWorkbook.VBProject _
        .VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)

        'Agrego FormGraficos
        With m_FormProgressBar
            .Name = "FrmProgress"
            .Properties("Name") = "FrmProgress"
            .Properties("width") = 240
            .Properties("height") = 80
            .Properties("Caption") = "Construyendo auditoría..."
            .Properties("ShowModal") = False
        End With
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new userform and setting its properties, I'm assuming you're showing the userform, and then removing it when finished.  If so, when you remove a newly created userform, it still remains in memory until the workbook is saved.  Hence, you'll get that error when you run the code a second time and give it the same name.  So either add `ThisWorkbook.Save` before the end of your procedure or simply don't name the userform and accept its default name.